# Invalid URL for CSS and JavaScript files in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, url, path

I'm using `WordPress 4.9.6`.

In the `<head>` tag include some line of codes with script and link tags for the plugins, but here happening something with the URL:

```
<script src="src="http://mydomain.test/wp-content/plugins/var/www/mydomain.test/wp-content/plugins/pluginsname/js/file.js"
```

And this need to be:

```
<script src="http://mydomain.test/wp-content/plugins/pluginsname/js/file.js"
```

It's looking like the WordPress mixing the URL and the file path...

What happening here and how can I fix this?

Comment: how are you writing code inside "src"? in head tag

Comment: you have to provide your *some line of codes with script and link tags * otherwise can't help u

Comment: @sayalok: there is an example code... I changed only the domain name in the code...

Comment: @charankumar: I use this code to insert that wrong script tags: <?php wp_head() ?>

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
<?php echo WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/plugin-name/js/file.js';?>
```

WP_PLUGIN_URL will give

```
http://mydomain.test/wp-content/plugins/
```

Comment: Isn't there any setting or configuration option what can set this globally?